# How to find difference, compare and get each field values in NSDate variables?

Tags: iphone, nsdate

How can i do the following operations on NSDate variables?

1. How to compare two NSDate variables?
2. How to find difference between two NSDate variables?
3. How to get each separate value of minute, hours and days from NSDate variable?

We can get the current date by

```
NSDate *currentDate=[NSDate date];
```

But it will give the result of 
    yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss GMT

From this, can i get hour field alone? or month value only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `NSDate` class reference, you have instance methods to do these -

1. How to compare two NSDate variables? **Ans:** `isEqualToDate:`
2. How to find difference between two NSDate variables? **Ans:** `timeIntervalSinceDate:`
3. How to get each separate value of minute, hours and days from NSDate variable? [links](http://tinyurl.com/4tqemhg)

**PS:** Use Google to the maximum.